# PHP Using Scandir with and External URL - Not Implemented

Tags: php, scandir

I'm having some trouble using scandir - I have it working fine on one site but now I'm wanting to scan the same directory on that site but from a different website.

I'm using the following code:

```
array_diff(scandir('http://sub.domain.co.uk/folder/folder/'), array('.', '..'));
```

and I get this error:

```
Warning: scandir(http://sub.domain.co.uk/folder/folder/): failed to open dir: not implemented
```

I've had a Google but brought up very little - I've tried enabling directory listing on the external site and allow_fopen_url is enabled as well.

I'm stumped, any help with this one?

Comment: The main problem with this one that there are **no directories** on the other site. Not a single one. Nor there is no filesystem to hold any directory or a file at all.

Comment: Removed the URL to the site I'm working on but there are definitely directories where I am looking. I'm scanning the exact same one locally and it works fine. Seems to be an issue with an external URL.

Comment: Of course locally you have the filesystem with all the files, directories, bells and whistles. Unfortunately, HTTP protocol doesn't have them all

Comment: Sorry, when I said 'locally' I meant using relative paths on the server.

Comment: Sure, relative path means local filesystem.

Comment: There are no directories online. That's what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a loop back problem, I was trying to scan a a folder on the same domain which was not allowed with my host.

I've had to introduce a 'state' to deal with this which says whether the software is live or not (because the software, once live, will actually point to a different domain).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the ftp extension loaded in PHP ([PHP: FTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)),  you could:

```
$connect = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($connect, $username, $password);

$contents = ftp_nlist($connect, ".");

print_r($contents);
```