# Can I list files on client pc through php server

Tags: php

I am trying to list the files on client pc through server, using php.
I am not sure if it is possible or not, I have tried following codes but not working, all are returning boolean false.

```
var_dump(scandir('http://192.168.30.4', 0));
var_dump(scandir('http://192.168.30.4/wamp', 0));
var_dump(scandir('http://192.168.30.4/wamp/testwebsite', 0));
var_dump(scandir('http://192.168.30.4/users', 0));
```

192.168.30.4 is client ip

Comment: php works serverside. if you need to execute code on the client machine, you need javascript (or any other clientside scripting language)

Comment: If arbitrary web pages were able to read the list of files on a client machine, that would be a huge security risk.  There's no supported way you can read arbitrary files/directory listings from clients' machines without the use of plugins (e.g. Java applet).

Answer (score 2):

`scandir()` won't work with HTTP URLs, because the HTTP protocol doesn't have a directory listing mechanism.

It's also unlikely that you're running an HTTP server on the client PC in the first place. If you are, it will only allow access to the files in the webserver's configuration, not full access to the PC's disks (unless the PC owner has made a serious mistake in configuring its webserver).

Finally, since you're using private IPs, the server wouldn't even be able to connect to the client PC unless the server is on the same network.

Comment: well the client and the server are on same server, even I access the server website using ip address

Comment: In a comment on the other answer, you said you're trying to copy files from the client to the server. If they're running on the same machine, why do you need to use `http:`? Just access the file as a local file: `scandir('/users/username')`

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you set up a web server on your PC to share the files explicitly, and then `scandir()` would be the wrong function to use.  You would want to use cURL or file streams using HTTP wrappers, and would want to know which files to request ahead of time.

It would be incredibly insecure if it were possible to have random computers on the internet search through your home computer arbitrarily.

Based on comments, it seems that you want to find a way to *more quickly* upload large files to your server.  Regardless of whether your server is requesting the files, or your home PC is initiating the upload, it will still take the same amount of time.

Comment: "No, because the client's PC is not running a web server.". what kind of answer is that?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio One that takes into account the person asking the question is trying to run HTTP requests against their user's IP address.

Comment: I just want to copy some files from my pc to server without uploading it, because the file is about 3 gb and taking a lot of time to just upload and definitely it will take more time to save the file on server

Comment: @SyedTalhaHai, your computer would still be sending the data to your server, regardless of if it's the server asking for the data, or your PC uploading it. A 3gb upload will still take a very long time, regardless of whether you try to push or pull.

Comment: @Ghedipunk "because client does not run a webserver" seems to imply "if the client was running a webserver it could be possible". but it is not.

Comment: @Ghedipunk do you mean 3gb upload using form and copying file from pc to server will take almost same time?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Of course it's possible, if they set up a web server on their home PC.  They just wouldn't be able to get _arbitrary_ files from that computer, only those that are explicitly shared in their web document root.

Comment: @SyedTalhaHai To get to the root of an actual solution... You want to use FTP.  It uses the least overhead (thus might speed things up by a few seconds over a few hours of transferring) and has the ability to resume upload if the connection is lost for some reason.

Comment: @Ghedipunk no way jose; scandir won't work on a remote system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254028/php-scandir-to-identify-contents-of-a-remote-drive     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836389/php-using-scandir-with-and-external-url-not-implemented   the only way to implement something like this is using FTP

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Please read my edit.  It explicitly says that scandir is the wrong thing to use, and suggests alternatives.

Comment: @Ghedipunk I for one appreciate your efforts, to make a good post edits must be considered (hence the +1 on your last comment). my point here is just about the different roles of a client machine and a server machine.